# excel vlookup output with colored cell

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup

I am trying to do a vlookup on a colored cell and return the output with background color. The value is getting returned but the background color is missing. I have tried in the following way. Please note that I am using Microsoft 365.

1. VBA Code:

```
Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim I As Long
    Dim xKeys As Long
    Dim xDicStr As String
    On Error Resume Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    xKeys = UBound(xDic.Keys)
    If xKeys >= 0 Then
        For I = 0 To UBound(xDic.Keys)
            xDicStr = xDic.Items(I)
            If xDicStr <> "" Then
                Range(xDic.Keys(I)).Interior.Color = _
                Range(xDic.Items(I)).Interior.Color
            Else
                Range(xDic.Keys(I)).Interior.Color = xlNone
            End If
        Next
        Set xDic = Nothing
    End If
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

2. Added the following module:

```
Public xDic As New Dictionary
Function LookupKeepColor (ByRef FndValue, ByRef LookupRng As Range, ByRef xCol As Long)
    Dim xFindCell As Range
    On Error Resume Next
    Set xFindCell = LookupRng.Find(FndValue, , xlValues, xlWhole)
    If xFindCell Is Nothing Then
        LookupKeepColor = ""
        xDic.Add Application.Caller.Address, ""
    Else
        LookupKeepColor = xFindCell.Offset(0, xCol - 1).Value
        xDic.Add Application.Caller.Address, xFindCell.Offset(0, xCol - 1).Address
    End If
End Function
```

3. Checked the Microsoft Script Runtime box in the References – VBAProject dialog box.
4. Used the following formula:

```
LOOKUPKEEPCOLOR(D3,Sheet1!$BS$6:Sheet1!$BT$13,2)
```